# Communication between host and servers in Docker containers

Tags: linux, python, node.js

Is there some software/framework/workaround that provide an easy way to exchange messages between the host and a container?

More specifically, I have a host running a Python server on Ubuntu. This host creates several containers running Node servers on an Ubuntu image. The host should send and receive messages to/from each container and they must not use the internet for this.

If there's no such software/framework, one possible workaround would be to write the messages to a file inside the container and the host reads them? Would it be possible to run several threads doing the same at the same time (each thread on a specific container)?

Comment: The question is not docker specific. It's just crossprocess communication and might be answered already years ago. And totally not at softwarerecs.

Comment: Actually, being docker born because of a pretty recent feature (cgroups) and a lot of new softwares being built on top of docker's existence, I wondered if a dedicated communication tool between host and container wouldn't be existing by now. 
Also, given that docker creates it's own private networks for inter-communication, it's not a crazy idea to build some interface on top of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sockets on the local host are the most usual way of doing this sort of thing - the file option can hit problems unless: a) Each thread has its own file & b) all writes are flushed and event then you can hit buffering problems & race conditions.

I would suggest that you look into using the built-in [Multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) Library with [Managers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#managers) to handle the interaction and data exchange. If the IP Addresses are all `('', port)` then traffic will be confined to the local machine. You will need a recent version of Python 3 and you will need to set up the appropriate port forwarding for your docker containers.

Comment: The "Managers" hint will also help me in another project! Thanks, I think this is the right way.